# Identify surface mount component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I am trying to identify and replace a component on a small power control board for a children's rocker.

The rocking function was stuck on for a while then completely failed.

I dissected the device and found some crispy looking components on the power input board.

There are two surface mount components highlighted in green boxes.

One is a resistor that measures at 50 ohms. I'm not sure what the other device even is. It appears it may have a Y2 stamped on the top but it's hard to discern, I figured I would try to fix it for fun.

[image]

Comment: Designator Q would indicate it is a transistor, with half-charred markings.

Comment: To me, Q4 begins with "28", with the rest of the number burned away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Y2 in the photo, but if that's what it is, SS8550 (a small PNP transistor) would be likely. Looks like a high-side switch connection. 2TY is a similar part S8550.

Comment: I used google and got a lot of hits with "IC y2". You might try and see if you can find it. It is possible the manufacturer could supply you with a parts list and/or a BOM.